# Pypark read CSV with 60516 columns taking longer time

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

The CSV file size is 130 MB but just reading and caching the file takes more than 5 minutes. I have set Inferschema as False and also it is taking much time. I tried with increasing cores, nodes , memory but no use. Any suggestions, please ?

Comment: how you read the file can you show the command.

Comment: R u using pyspark??

Comment: Hi @sahil desai tried both scala and pyspark, but same results

Comment: Any suggestions??

Comment: @sahildesai inferring schema will scan data twice.

Comment: I am unable to do the count operation itself from spark-shell. I am confused whether I am missing something, or Spark is not good for CSV with larger columns?

Comment: `spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header‌​='true', inferschema='true').load('file.csv')` try this

Comment: no that's not true I used csv (2gb) into spark and it was properly running.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is somewhat expected behavior or rather known weak side of Apache Spark. Structured API (Spark SQL / Dataset) scales poorly (depending on the context and version complexity might grow even exponentially) in terms of number of fields used for the query. Luckily this is constant overhead (doesn't depend on the number of rows).

If you work with very wide data, and require low latency, it might be wise to skip Spark SQL, and go back to RDD API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I hope this might be what I am looking for. I will try this and update

Comment: This is working !!. Earlier, my count program stucks forever but now it is working within seconds. Finally got a solution. Thanks man!!